# Contador simple em Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Olá,

Estou fazendo um contador bem simples em javascript, porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que o
for apareça no navegador, só está aparecendo o ultimo numero do laço. Quando testo no console o resultado aparece correto. Porém, quando é para mostrar no HTML não funciona. segue os códigos

```js
function executar() { 

  let inicio = document.getElementById('inicio')
  let fim = document.getElementById('fim')
  let passo = document.getElementById('passo')
  let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado')

  if( inicio.value.length == 0 || fim.value.length == 0 || passo.value.length == 0){
    window.alert('Complete os dados')
  } else {
    resultado.innerHTML = 'Contando:'
    let i = Number(inicio.value)
    let f = Number(fim.value)
    let p = Number(passo.value)
    if (p == 0){
      p = 1
    }


    if ( i < f){
    for (let c = i; c <= f; c+=p){
     resultado.innerHTML = `${c} \u{1F449}`
   }
  } else {
      for(let c = i; c>= f ; c-= p){
        resultado.innerHTML += `${c} \u{1F449}`
      }
  }
  resultado.innerHTML += `\u{1F3C1}`

  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Site 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>
<body >
    <header>

        <h1>Site 3</h1>

    </header>
    <section>
        <div>
            <p>Inicio
            <input type="number" name="inicio" id="inicio">
        </p>
            <p>Fim
            <input type="number" name="fim" id="fim">
        </p>
            <p>Passo
            <input type="number" name="passo" id="passo">
        </p>
             
            <input type="button" value="Executar" onclick="executar()">
             </p>
            
        </div>
        <div id="resultado">
            Preencha os dados...
        </div>


    </section>
    <footer>

        <p>&copy; Henrique</p>

    </footer>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente precisa mostrar os dados conforme o inicio e fim com determinado passo a passo, fez certo (basicamente) mas, no momento de mostrar deveria ser acumulativo e no fim das contas o seu código mostra sempre o último porque o texto não é concatenado e sim alterado por isso só mostra o último:

```js
function executar() {

  let inicio = document.getElementById('inicio')
  let fim = document.getElementById('fim')
  let passo = document.getElementById('passo')
  let resultado = document.getElementById('resultado')

  if (inicio.value.length == 0 || fim.value.length == 0 || passo.value.length == 0) {
    window.alert('Complete os dados')
  } else {
    resultado.innerHTML = 'Contando:'
    let i = Number(inicio.value)
    let f = Number(fim.value)
    let p = Number(passo.value)
    if (p == 0) {
      p = 1
    }


    if (i < f) {
      for (let c = i; c <= f; c += p) {
        resultado.innerHTML += `${c} \u{1F449}`
      }
    } else {
      for (let c = i; c >= f; c -= p) {
        resultado.innerHTML += `${c} \u{1F449}`
      }
    }
    resultado.innerHTML += `\u{1F3C1}`

  }

}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Inicio
    <input type="number" name="inicio" id="inicio">
  </p>
  <p>Fim
    <input type="number" name="fim" id="fim">
  </p>
  <p>Passo
    <input type="number" name="passo" id="passo">
  </p>

  <input type="button" value="Executar" onclick="executar()">
  </p>

</div>
<div id="resultado">
  Preencha os dados...
</div>
```

ou seja, faltou colocar `+=` nessa linha **resultado.innerHTML = `${c} \u{1F449}`**

Um pouco melhor o código:

```js
function getElement(name) {
  return document.getElementById(name);
}
function valid(obj) {
  return obj && obj.value.length === 0;
}
function parse(obj) {
  return Number(obj.value)
}
function print(i, f, p, obj) {
  if (i < f) {
    for (let c = i; c <= f; c += p) {
        obj.innerHTML += `${c} \u{1F449}`
    }
  } else {
    for (let c = i; c >= f; c -= p) {
        resultado.innerHTML += `${c} \u{1F449}`
    }
  }
}
function executar() {
  const inicio = getElement('inicio')
  const fim = getElement('fim')
  const passo = getElement('passo')
  const resultado = getElement('resultado')

  if (valid(inicio) || valid(fim) || valid(passo)) {
    window.alert('Complete os dados')
  } else {
    resultado.innerHTML = 'Contando:'
    const i = parse(inicio);
    const f = parse(fim);
    const p = parse(passo);
    print(i, f, p, resultado);
    resultado.innerHTML += `\u{1F3C1}`
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Inicio
    <input type="number" name="inicio" id="inicio">
  </p>
  <p>Fim
    <input type="number" name="fim" id="fim">
  </p>
  <p>Passo
    <input type="number" name="passo" id="passo">
  </p>

  <input type="button" value="Executar" onclick="executar()">
  </p>

</div>
<div id="resultado">
  Preencha os dados...
</div>
```

Comment: Acho que entendi errado a pergunta.

Comment: è complicado muitas vezes entender, mas, a ajuda do código na pergunta foi fundamental para responder @AugustoVasques ...

Comment: Show, obrigado era somente o += que estava faltando